# 'globalThis' underfined for Jest test cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I am using globalThis property specifically globalThis.scrollTo(0,0) in my React WebApp.

I am using Jest for unit testing alongwith Enzyme.

As of test cases fail as it is unable to identify globalThis and says that 'globalThis' is undefined.

Is there a way to introduce globalThis into the tests just like jsdom does for window etc ?

For Example

-- abc.tsx --

```
const abc: React.FC<CustomProps> = props => {
useEffect(() => {
globalThis?.scrollTo(0,0);
}
}
```

-- abcTest.tsx --

```
wrapper = mount(<abc/>);
```

**mount** produces error that "globalThis" is undefined

Comment: Please share some of your code, at least your test code.

Comment: This may help, a similar error was reported to jsdom ("ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined") - https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2795

Comment: What version of node, jest, and jsdom is installed?

Comment: Node version is 8, Jest is 24 and Jest is 16. Could updating Node to 12 work ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[globalThis](https://v8.dev/features/globalthis) needs node version 12+. I use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) as node version management.

```js
console.log(globalThis);
```

For `node/10.16.2`, got error:

```
console.log(globalThis);
            ^

ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
```

For `node/12.6.1`, got:

```
Object [global] {
  global: [Circular],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] { [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function] },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function]
  }
}
```

See also, MDN [globalThis#compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#browser_compatibility)

Comment: I am using the version node 15X and having the same error...

Comment: I'm getting this error on 14.17.6 & 16.18.0 for my Angular app

Answer (score 1):

You can add these code to the top

```js
!function(t){function e(){var e=this||self;e.globalThis=e,delete t.prototype._T_}"object"!=typeof globalThis&&(this?e():(t.defineProperty(t.prototype,"_T_",{configurable:!0,get:e}),_T_))}(Object);
```

[More details](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/globalthis)